# $\varphi_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge\varphi_{i_k}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ as a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $e_1\dots,e_n$ be the standard basis of $\mathbf R^n$ and let $\varphi_1\dots,\varphi_n$ be the dual basis. I need to show that $\varphi_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge\varphi_{i_k}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is the determinant of the $k\times k$ minor of $(v_1,\dots, v_k)^T$ obtained by selecting columns $i_1,\dots, i_k$.

By definition, $$\varphi_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge\varphi_{i_k}(v_1,\dots,v_k)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_k} \operatorname{sgn}\sigma\cdot\varphi_{i_1}(v_{\sigma(1)})\dots\varphi_{i_k}(v_{\sigma(k)}),$$
but I don't know what simplifications I should do further.

Comment: That formula with the sign and the permutations is the determinant.

Comment: What definition of determinant are you using?

Comment: @TrevorGunn It certainly looks like the the determinant, but it's not obvious to me that this is the determinant of the matrix described.

Comment: @mucciolo I'm allowed to use any definition; I guess the one involving permutations would be the most appropriate.

Comment: It looks like the transpose determinant ... which equals the determinant.

Comment: @orangeskid How do you see that? I don't even see why the terms $\varphi_{i_r}(v_{\sigma(r)})$ can be considered as the entries $a_{ij}$ of some matrix $(a_{ij})$.

Comment: If $v_i = (v_{i,1},\dots,v_{i,n})$ then $\varphi_j(v_i) = v_{i,j}$.